# Overwrite generated id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I write integration tests for Spring Application.

For testing I use Spock Framework.

The problem is that I want to save 2 objects before each test and I want to delete all objects after each test.

When I call test method `findById` for id 1 and 2 I get these objects.
But when I call `findById` test again for id 1 and 2 I get objects with id 3 and 4.

Hibernate strategy for id I use is:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

And the question is how can I test it or how can I force hibernate not to create new identifiers?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a common setup for all tests in this class? If so, have you thought about:

```
class TestClass extends Specification {
   def entity1 = null
   def entity2 = null

   def setup() {
       entity1 = em.save(... your entity...)
       entity2 = em.save(... your entity...)
   }

   def cleanup() {
       em.delete(entity1)
       em.delete(entity2)
   }

    def "some test"() {
        // do your test stuff...
    }
}
```

I would avoid extensive modification in your production code just to make tests easier. There usually is a good solution for most problems.

Comment: Yes, my setup looks like this, but I use @Before

Comment: Alright... but you do have the saved entities, and you do have the ids. What is the problem then?

Comment: When first test run I have in db 2 objects with id 1 and 2. And if I call findById for 1 and 2 I get success test, because entities which are in db in this time have these ids. But when next test run in db I have 2 objects, but with id 3 and 4 and tests are failure.

Comment: Such tests are non-deterministic

Comment: You want to have a deterministic test but your ID generator is not. Think about what you are really testing. Do you want to verify that EntityManager stored your entity properly ? Or that em.find(Class, ID) works correctly? Or that your mappings are set properly?

Comment: The most important are http statuses of response and that depends on what the database returns

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this - the IDs are generated not by Hibernate but (in this case) by your DB. When hibernate INSERTs the database increments its counter. This cannot be undone without re-creating the table.

If you wish to assign IDs manually, you'd have to use a different strategy - e.g. `assigned` (it's not a part of JPA but is present in Hibernate). Though this will impact your production code as well which you don't want to do.

Instead you shouldn't rely on hardcoded IDs - you can get them from the entity itself:

```
  Blah b = dao.save(Blah.random();
  flushAndClear();
  Blah fromDB = dao.findById(b.getId);
```

You can read more about how to write DAO-layer tests [here](http://qala.io/blog/test-pyramid.html).